# Integrate Lobibox message box with default confirm model

Tags: jquery

Can anybody help me how to integrate lobibox message box with default confirm model. When i click the delete option, the lobibox appears but before i choose any option 'yes 'or 'no', it will delete the data. I am trying to use lobibox first time. I read the documentation many times but no any ideas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.deleteit').click(function(){
        var lobibox = Lobibox.confirm({
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete ?"


    });
});
```

```
<a href="{{route('order.delete',[$m->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger deleteit" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting images, posting your code will help.

Comment: i did put code i know . help me guys